# why is some of the blue code in visual studio c# a little bit ligher than the rest

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

there seem to have links between the declared variables and when it's used, if so how do I link them?

[image: light blue text for variables]

Comment: The lighter highlighting means the syntax is redundant / not necessary.  I imagine you are not using auto properties where you should be.  Also `this.` is most of the time not needed anymore.  You should include your _actual_ code in the body of your question in _addition_ to the screenshot you have already provided

Comment: It's optional/unused code.

Answer (score 3):

It means you don't really need that piece of code. If you click on that light bulb on the left, Visual Studio will tell you why this is redundant.